# When Tsunade told Naruto to not use the Rasenshuriken, couldn't he have just used a clone?

Tags: naruto

He used a clone as a distraction against Kakuzu, so couldn't he do that again without using sage mode?

Comment: This kills the clone.

Comment: doesn't the jutsu just have to hit the enemy, unless you need to push down the rasengan to have any effect, so it also wouldnt really matter if the clone "died" just as long as the rasengan hit? or i could be wrong

Comment: In the battle against Kakuzu, its conclusively shown that a Shadow Clone can carry the Rasenshuriken. The clone will dissipate once the shockwave from impact hits it.

Comment: Also, those saying clone would dissipate before the attack hits are forgetting something. Naruto throwing the Rasenshuriken wouldn't mean much if just holding it can cause the damage, since he is holding it in his hand till its complete.

Answer (score 1):

The Rasenshuriken was originally told to be off-limits due to the physical damage inflicted by its use.  Because Naruto used it like a traditional Rasengan, which requires that the jutsu make direct contact with the enemy, the damage done to his person couldn't be avoided.

The reason that a clone could not work in this scenario would be due to the fact that clones are dispelled once sufficiently high physical damage is inflicted to it.  It would be my belief that a clone could never sustain its form long enough to sustain a hit with the Rasenshuriken before it - and the jutsu - were dispelled.

Comment: In the fight against Kakuzu, Naruto had a clone carry a completed Rasenshuriken to make Kauzu believe it was the real one. The clone would only be dispelled once the attack made contact and it would be too late then.

Answer (score -5):

is simple, (it's my opinion. i am not kishimoto) because the kage-bunshin cannot strong hold the Rasenshuriken, so the kage-bunshin will dissapear.

it also show, on this anime, if naruto use the rasengan he will use the real body not kage-bunshin.

Comment: doesn't the jutsu just have to hit the enemy, unless you need to push down the rasengan to have any effect, so it also wouldnt really matter if the clone "died" just as long as the rasengan hit? or i could be wrong

Comment: He's saying he wouldn't be able to carry it to the enemy in the first place.

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade In the battle against Kakuzu, its conclusively shown that a Shadow Clone can carry the Rasenshuriken. The clone will dissipate once the shockwave from impact hits it